# Como obter o nome da tabela de um model?

Tags: laravel

Preciso pegar o nome da tabela que é utilizada por determinado `model` na minha aplicação escrita em `Laravel`.

Antigamente, no `Laravel 3`, era necessário fazer apenas isso para descobrir o nome da tabela:

```
   var_dump(MeuModel::$table);
```

Porém, no `Laravel 4 >=` essa propriedade não é mais estática, e muito menos `public`.

Por exemplo:

```
 class Usuario extends Eloquent
 {
    protected $table = 'tbl_usuarios';
 }
```

Ou seja, com a propriedade sendo `protected` não é possível pegá-la "fora da instância do model".

Preciso que, no Controller, eu consiga pegar o valor de `protected $table` para exibi-lo.

Existe alguma maneira de fazer isso no `Laravel`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para obter no nome da tabela de um model basta usar o método `getTable`, que é herdado de `Eloquent`.

```
$tabela_usuarios = (new Usuario)->getTable();
```